# Looking at bottom of Kiddush cup - why?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, kiddush

I've seen in the past that it is proper to look into the Kiddush cup (iirc looking to the bottom of the cup) before making the blessing of *boreh peri hagefen*, i.e. when saying "*savri*...". I think it is a Sefardi thing, but I can't find any reference to it in Yalkut Yosef, so could be wrong about that.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: This is probably to fulfill the 10 [11] things done with a blessing-cup (brachot 51a). (Roughly translated: wiping, washing, fresh, full, crowning, wrapping, taking with two hands, holding in the right hand, lifting up, looking at it[, sharing with wife].)

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the line of enquiry. What's the 10th?

Comment: Oops skipped "full". Edited in. This is definitely the reason to look at the cup, I'm just not posting an answer since it doesn't specify to look into the bottom specifically.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks. I am also fairly sure that the time of looking is specifically "savri", so a source referencing that would be ideal

Comment: The Rama asks how can you look at candles during kiddush if you have to look at the cup? He says to look at candles for vaychulul and cup for kiddush. Meaning you switch to cup at savri. I'm guessing you are mistaking looking from savri on for at savri specifically.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks, will look at the Rama bli neder

Comment: [בא"ח ש"ש פרשת בראשית סעי' כ"ט](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%90%22%D7%97_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA#%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%98)

Comment: My late father used to do this, and we're Ashkenazim of Litvak descent, so I'm not sure that it is just a Sefardi thing.  That said, he did grow up davening in a Sefardi shul, but I'm not aware of him taking on any other Sefardi minhagim.

Comment: @MosesSupposes did he look to the _bottom of the cup_ or just look _at the cup_?

Comment: I think he used to look in to the cup from above

Answer (score 2):

HaMaran Ben ish Chai [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai,_Halachot_2nd_Year,_Bereshit_29.5) to look "within the cup" before making the blessing, and there are 'secrets' associated with this practice.

> ואחר המזיגה תתן עיניך בכוס היין ותסתכל בו, ויש סוד עמוק וכוונה גדולה בהסתכלות זו.

As far as I've seen concerning looking specifically at the bottom of the cup, it could very well be a misconstrued translation or inference from the word "בכוס."

There is a also a practice to look at either the wine or the cup during kiddush to not lose concentration. Pitchei teshuva.

See Rama [סי' רע"א סעי' י']:

> וכשמתחיל (לעשות קידוש) – יתן עיניו בנרות, ובשעת הקידוש – בכוס של ברכה

The mishna berura, explains:

> שלא יסיח דעתו

To not lose concentration on what one is currently making a blessing on.

Comment: This doesn't mention the bottom of the cup anywhere

Comment: The op never said it was a given. Only "iirc"... I'm looking for that though to edit into the answer

Comment: @Shababnik thanks, the fact that I also recall (perhaps incorrectly) that it is Sefardi, I believe it is likely it is out there. I plan to go through my siddurim this Shabbat and might find something

Comment: @RabbiKaii let me know what you find

Comment: Btw the meaning of ויש סוד עמוק... Is not that there are secrets _in_ the cup. Rather that there are secrets in the minhag of looking in the cup (I'm not sure if that's what you meant. if it is, it wasn't clear to me)

Comment: @Loani I meant in this practice when I wrote "therein"

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thanks for clarifying